# AWS CLI: Pass arguments to --user-data(shell-script) in aws ec2 run-instances

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to launch an aws ec2 instance via cli.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 \
 --instance-type t2.medium --key-name myKey \
 --security-group-ids sg-yyyyyyyy --subnet-id subnet-mysubnet \ 
 --region us-east-1 --user-data file://myscript
```

While launching I call a shell script that runs some basic commands.
I was wondering if there is a way to pass arguments to this

```
--user-data file://myscript
```

sample shell script:

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: no, but I found a work around. I was executing the script via Jenkins, so I made use of "sed" command. You can learn about it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-unix/
Do check the answers by  Frédéric Henri and John Rotenstein below.

Comment: OK thanks for the speedy response. We're using a similar workaround *sigh* ¯\_༼ᴼل͜ᴼ༽_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can, at least we never did this way.

However what we did is to install awcli tool (through pip for example) in our user data, and read a JSon file store on s3 with all the necessary parameters.

At the end it gave us more flexibility between teams as the cloud formation script were not touched, and we maintained separately the values and version of software we had to install.

Answer (score 1):

You could either create the `myscript` file with parameters, and then call `run-instances`, or you could pass parameters on the command-line:

```
aws ec2 run-instances ... --user-data "#!\naws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $INSTANCE\n"
```

The above inserts shell variables into the command, but this can get a bit messy. It's probably better to have a script that creates the `myscript` file and passes it into the command.